# Закрывается форма при нажатии на Enter C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

При нажатии на Enter должен появляться MessageBox , но вместо этого приложение просто закрывается. В чем может быть проблема?

Форму делал из TableLayout. Скрин -> https://prnt.sc/1z4skf3  Фото добавить в вопрос не вышло т.к. пишет "ошибка сервера"

Брекпоинты ставил , он даже не видит нажатие клавиши

```
//Обрабатываем нажатие и если клавиша - Enter то передаем значения и выполняем метод
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                Searcher searcher = new Searcher(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text, TextBox4.Text, TextBox5.Text, TextBox6.Text);
                searcher.Set();
            }
        }
```

Собственно сам метод

```
public class Searcher
    {
        private string _last_name; //Фамилия
        private string _first_name; //имя
        private string _middle_name; //Отчество
        private string _debt_id; //ID Дела
        private string _kd; //№ КД
        private string _exec_num; //№ Дела

        public Searcher(string last_name, string first_name, string middle_name, string debt_id, string kd, string exec_num)
        {
            _last_name = last_name;
            _first_name = first_name;
            _middle_name = middle_name;
            _debt_id = debt_id;
            _kd = kd;
            _exec_num = exec_num;
        }
        public void Set()
        {
            MessageBox.Show(_last_name);
        }
```

Comment: Вероятней всего вы не попадаете в метод Form1_KeyDown, так как форма не находится в фокусе . Я увидел на вашем Скрине что у вас есть текстовые поля , по которым вы вероятно и осуществляете поиск, привяжите событие Enter К этим полям , когда вы будете что то печатать в этих полях они будут находится уже в фокусе .

Comment: @ДанилСтрученков да, я пробовал создавать событие именно на текстбоксы.

В таком случае если текстбоксы находятся в фокусе все работает прекрасно, но если в фокусе находится форма, к примеру, после запуска или клика на шапку), то она закрывается

Comment: Попробуйте использовать событие PreviewKeyDown вероятно KeyDown просто обрабатывается контролом, который находится в клавиатурном фокусе и дальше не идет.

Comment: Если есть возможность то проверьте действительно ли ваша форма находится в фокусе. Возможно там есть событие Focused и Unfocused

Comment: Еще есть свойство `Form.KeyPreview` https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview?view=netcore-3.0 Оно наверное даже лучше для вашей ситуации подходит.

Comment: Enter должен срабатывать в каждом текстбоксе? | Может, вам [AcceptButton](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) нужно?

Answer (score 1):

В общем ничего не помогло, даже PreviewKeyDown.

Решил проблему следующим образом. При загрузке формы принудительно поставил текстбокс в фокус. Таким образом при загрузке формы и нажатии на enter форма не вылетает.

```
Textbox1.Focus();
```

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/designate-a-wf-button-as-the-accept-button-using-the-designer?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: Задайте значения свойства `TabIndex` для всех контролов, чтобы фокус переходил по ним в нужном порядке.